# Securing SOAP Web-Services using WSS4J Library (Spring WITHOUT MVC)

Tags: spring, web-services, spring-security, interceptor, wss4j

I am new to spring web services.I am doing an interceptor on the sage.xml (otherwse, known as spring-ws-servlet.xml) in my project by using eclipse.

Without the interceptors and it's handler. The web services work fine, but once added the interceptor the error was prompt.

I have no idea why it is prompting errors.I suspected the libraries problem. I can't figure it out can anyone help me with this?

**The following is the error message.**

```
    Apr 30, 2014 2:27:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.29 using APR version 1.4.8.
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013)
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1173 ms
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\conf\Catalina\localhost\task4.xml
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:51 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
INFO: Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:51 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Apr 30 14:27:51 SGT 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:51 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/sage.xml]
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:51 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider registerDefaultFilters
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:51 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1655d7e: defining beans [govUserEndpoint,govUserInterfaceImplementation,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,final,org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#1,callbackHandler,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:52 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1655d7e: defining beans [govUserEndpoint,govUserInterfaceImplementation,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,final,org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#0,org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#1,callbackHandler,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:52 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.DelegatingSmartSoapEndpointInterceptor#1': Cannot create inner bean 'wss4jSecurityInterceptor' of type [org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wss4jSecurityInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/sage.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/security/Init
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:616)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:148)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:939)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:670)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'wss4jSecurityInterceptor' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/config/sage.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/security/Init
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xml/security/Init
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.setXmlSecIgnoreLineBreak(WSSConfig.java:400)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.init(WSSConfig.java:420)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.getNewInstance(WSSConfig.java:455)
    at org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngine.getWssConfig(WSSecurityEngine.java:142)
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.java:496)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xml.security.Init
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    ... 40 more

Apr 30, 2014 2:27:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/task4] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\docs
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\examples
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:54 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\host-manager
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\manager
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Java\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\ROOT
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Apr 30, 2014 2:27:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8494 ms
Apr 30, 2014 2:39:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 30, 2014 2:39:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Apr 30, 2014 2:39:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Apr 30, 2014 2:39:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 30, 2014 2:39:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Apr 30, 2014 2:39:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Apr 30, 2014 2:39:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
```

**The libraries I have are,**

```
aopalliance-1.0.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-lang-2.5.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-ws-core-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-ws-security-2.1.4.RELEASE .jar
spring-xml-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar
stax-api-1.0-2.jar
wsdl4j-1.6.1.jar
wss4j-1.6.13.jar
XmlSchema-1.4.3.jar
```

**My web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID"
         version="2.5">

    <!--
        Spring-ws-configuraion file.
    -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/config/sage.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!--
        Loads the Spring web application context, using the files defined above.
    -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!--
        Define the Spring WS Servlet. The 'transformWsldLocations' param means
        that any WSDLs generated are context-aware and contain the correct
        path to their exposed port types. The 'contextConfigLocation' param
        with an empty value means that the Spring context won't try to load
        a file called webservices-servlet.xml
    -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>transformWsdlLocations</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.wsdl</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>webservices</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/endpoints/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**My sage.xml (spring-ws-servlet.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"

    xsi:schemaLocation="    
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  ">

    <!-- Here point to your interface and implementation package -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.example.service" />

    <!-- Here is the name for the web address -->
    <bean id="final"
        class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition"
        lazy-init="true">
        <property name="schemaCollection">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.commons.CommonsXsdSchemaCollection">

                <property name="inline" value="true" />

                <property name="xsds">
                    <list>
                        <!-- Here point to schemas folder of the operation service XSD!! -->
                        <value>schema/GovUserOperationService.xsd</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>

        </property>
        <property name="portTypeName" value="GovUserServices" />
        <property name="serviceName" value="GovUserService" />
        <property name="locationUri" value="/endpoints" />
    </bean>

    <sws:interceptors>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.SoapEnvelopeLoggingInterceptor" />
        <bean id="wss4jSecurityInterceptor"
            class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor">
            <property name="validationCallbackHandler" ref="callbackHandler" />
            <property name="validationActions" value="UsernameToken" />
        </bean>
    </sws:interceptors>

    <bean id="callbackHandler"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j.callback.SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler">
        <property name="users">
            <props>
                <prop key="admin">password</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Comment: For starters your dependencies are a mess fix those. You are mixing spring version (3.1.1 and 3.0.5) and you are mixing Spring-WS versions (2.0.0 and 2.1.4). Never mix versions of a framework that is trouble waiting to happen. To fix the classnotfound you need the [xmlsec.jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.santuario%22%20AND%20a%3A%22xmlsec%22) on your classpath. I also strongly suggest using maven or gradle to manage your dependencies instead of trying to figure out which ones to use yourself. Saves you a lot of time.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I am doing my internship in my company. My superiors do not want it to be done through either maven or gardle. I am totally lost where did i mixed up the versions? and meaning of classpath is the classpath in the sage.xml file? or the libraries? Please help.

Comment: Your spring-aop is of version 3.1.1. whereas spring-web[mvc] is of version 3.0.5. That isn't going to work. The same for sprnig-ws but with different versions. Isn't the goal of an internship learning how to do things in real life, not being able to use proper tools isn't a thing you should have to learn.